# Why does useSelector return initial state while in redux dev tool it shows updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using redux and am not sure that why do I get initial state when try to access but it shows updated state in redux dev tool.

What I am doing:
I have two buttons **"Yes"**, **"No"** and in reducer, I have initial state so when i click on **"yes"** button I update the initial state using dispatch method and I am able to see updated state in redux dev tool but when i access state from redux in **"No"** button's click function it shows initial states:

**reducer.js**

```
import { SET_MODAL_DETAILS, CLEAR_MODAL_DETAILS } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  modalInfo: {
    isOpen: false,
    modalName: "",
    title: "",
    content: "",          
  },
};

const modal = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case SET_MODAL_DETAILS:
      return { ...state, modalInfo: payload };

    case CLEAR_MODAL_DETAILS:
      return { ...state, modalInfo: null };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default modal;
```

**action.js**

```
import {SET_MODAL_DETAILS, CLEAR_MODAL_DETAILS} from "./types";

export const setModalDetails = (payload) => ({
    type: SET_MODAL_DETAILS,
    payload: payload,
});

export const clearModalDetails = () => ({
    type: CLEAR_MODAL_DETAILS,
});
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import checkTokenExpiration from "./checkToken";

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? applyMiddleware(...middleware, checkTokenExpiration)
    : composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware, checkTokenExpiration))
);

export default store;
```

**student.js**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { setModalDetails } from "../../redux/actions/modal";

const Student = ({ setModalDetails, modal: { modalInfo } }) => {
  const handleYesButton = () => {
    setModalDetails({
      ...modalInfo,
      isOpen: true,
      title: "Confirm Modal",
      content: "Do you want to change status?",
      modalName: "confirmModal",
    });
  };

  const handleNoButton = () => {
    console.log(modalInfo); // returns initial state while I have updated via above funtion
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleYesButton}>Yes</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleNoButton}>No</Button>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  modal: state.modal,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setModalDetails })(Student);
```

Comment: You never use `dispatch` in this code

Comment: yes instead of using dispatch I am using connect, I have updated code, please check

Comment: Code updated please have a look

Comment: Should be `const Student = ({ 
      modal: { modalInfo }, setModalDetails 
    }) => {`

Comment: That was typo mistake sorry for this. Code is working properly, problem is related to redux state that why does it not return updated state.

Comment: Why are you using both the `connect` Higher Order Component ***and*** the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks in the same component? You've double declared the `modalInfo` variable. Assuming one or the other of `connect` HOC or the redux hooks is working correctly I don't see any overt issues with the code. There's also not really enough code to provide context enough to say why you're not seeing expected state in a callback. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] that includes all relevant code you reference?

Comment: @DrewReese I was checking both HOC and hooks but both of them is not working. I have update code and add store file code as well.

Comment: Does the `SET_MODAL_DETAILS` action run when you call `setModalDetails`?

Comment: yes, thats why I am able to see updated state in redux tool

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live? I'm not seeing any overt issues in the code you've shared so far.

Comment: Should be `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  modalInfo: state.modalInfo,
});` and `const Student = ({ setModalDetails, modalInfo }) => {`

Comment: @Konrad it's returning undefined.

Comment: @DrewReese I have created code on codesandbox and it's working fine so i think issue is in my code structure

Comment: @DrewReese I have figured out the issue. If I pass both functions from parent component then it's not working as expected but if I use both function in child component like in student.js then it's working. Could you suggest why?

Comment: Please check the created code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sid-0h9d2t?file=/src/parent.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I pass both functions from parent component then it's not working
> as expected but if I use both function in child component like in
> `student.js` then it's working. Could you suggest why?

It all works in `Student` (student.js) because `Student` is directly subscribed to the `state.modal` state from the store. When the store updates, `Student` is rerendered with the latest selected `modal` state value injected as a prop and `modal.modalInfo` is re-enclosed in the `handleNoButton` function scope. When the "no" button is clicked, it has the current `modalInfo` value.

In the case where the button click handlers *aren't* working in `StudentA` (studentA.js) it is because you've closed over a stale copy of the `state.modal.modalInfo` in some local state that is never updated.

```
const Parent = ({ setModalDetails, modal: { modalInfo } }) => {
  const handleYesButton = () => {
    setModalDetails({
      ...modalInfo,
      isOpen: true,
      title: "Confirm Modal",
      content: "Do you want to change status?",
      modalName: "confirmModal"
    });
  };

  const handleNoButton = () => {
    console.log("from parent: ", modalInfo);
  };

  const [
    confirmOptions,
    setConfirmOptions // <-- never called to update confirmOptions
  ] = useState({
    buttons: [
      {
        label: "Yes",
        onClick: handleYesButton // <-- store state closed over!
      },
      {
        label: "No",
        onClick: handleNoButton  // <-- store state closed over!
      }
    ]
  });

  return <StudentA options={confirmOptions} />;
};
```

When the redux state is updated and `Parent` rerenders, `setConfirmOptions` isn't called to update the `confirmOptions` value, thus `StudentA` is passed the current `confirmOptions` state which now contains stale redux state values.

If you want to create an options object to be passed down then just compute it directly and pass it down. This way a new `confirmOptions` object is created with the current selected state value any time `Parent` renders.

Example:

```
const confirmOptions = {
  buttons: [
    {
      label: "Yes",
      onClick: handleYesButton
    },
    {
      label: "No",
      onClick: handleNoButton
    }
  ]
};

return <StudentA options={confirmOptions} />;
```

[image: Edit why-does-useselector-return-initial-state-while-in-redux-dev-tool-it-shows-updat]

If doing this triggers more `StudentA` renders than is necessary or if it was an expensive computation to create the object, you should use the `useMemo` hook to memoize and provide a stable options object. Note, however, that `handleYesButton` and `handleNoButton` would be external dependencies in creating the `confirmOptions` object, and so they too would need to be memoized in order to provide stable references.

Example:

```
const handleYesButton = useCallback(() => {
  setModalDetails({
    ...modalInfo,
    isOpen: true,
    title: "Confirm Modal",
    content: "Do you want to change status?",
    modalName: "confirmModal"
  });
}, [setModalDetails, modalInfo]);

const handleNoButton = useCallback(() => {
  console.log("from parent: ", modalInfo);
}, [modalInfo]);

const confirmOptions = useMemo(
  () => ({
    buttons: [
      {
        label: "Yes",
        onClick: handleYesButton
      },
      {
        label: "No",
        onClick: handleNoButton
      }
    ]
  }),
  [handleNoButton, handleYesButton]
);

return <StudentA options={confirmOptions} />;
```

or because `handleYesButton` and `handleNoButton` aren't referenced anywhere else in `Parent` they can be moved into the `useMemo` hook callback.

```
const confirmOptions = useMemo(
  () => ({
    buttons: [
      {
        label: "Yes",
        onClick: () => {
          setModalDetails({
            ...modalInfo,
            isOpen: true,
            title: "Confirm Modal",
            content: "Do you want to change status?",
            modalName: "confirmModal"
          });
        }
      },
      {
        label: "No",
        onClick: () => {
          console.log("from parent: ", modalInfo);
        }
      }
    ]
  }),
  [modalInfo, setModalDetails]
);

return <StudentA options={confirmOptions} />;
```